# Gnome Is glitching after recent update

Tags: gnome, updates, screen, desktop-environments, 20.10

Good morning everybody,
After a recent update to my 20.10 Ubuntu device, a new problem with GNOME appeared where everything is glitching specially when I open a GTK based window like "Terminal" and there are lines that flicker through the screen (like tv static) and the Screen windows gets mixed....

- GNOME version: 3.38.3
- Windowing System: X11
- GPU: Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
- CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz × 4
- Kernel: 5.8.0-50-generic

Video: https://streamable.com/7fpimk

$ **systemctl --failed**

```
  UNIT                                                  LOAD   ACTIVE SUB    DE>
● snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service loaded failed failed Se>
● teamviewerd.service                                   loaded failed failed Te>
● varnishncsa.service                                   loaded failed failed Va>

LOAD   = Reflects whether the unit definition was properly loaded.
ACTIVE = The high-level unit activation state, i.e. generalization of SUB.
SUB    = The low-level unit activation state, values depend on unit type.

3 loaded units listed.
```

$ **journalctl -p 3 -b**

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2021-05-05 19:24:49 EET, end at Wed 2021-05-05 19:58:45 EET. --
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: file '/var/log/syslog'[7] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: file '/var/log/syslog'[7] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: file '/var/log/syslog'[7] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: file '/var/log/syslog'[7] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: file '/var/log/syslog'[7] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: file '/var/log/syslog'[7] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: file '/var/log/syslog'[7] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: file '/var/log/syslog'[7] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: file '/var/log/syslog'[7] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: action 'action-2-builtin:omfile' (module 'builtin:omfile') message lost, could not be processed. Check for additional error messages before this one. [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
May 05 19:24:53 Stack-Linux rsyslogd[1508]: file '/var/log/syslog'[7] write error - see https://www.rsyslog.com/solving-rsyslog-write-errors/ for help OS error: No space left on device [v8.2006.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2027 ]
```

Smiliar Problem: https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/lavwee/gnome_3383_screen_glitches_and_freezes_with_black/
https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/lavvcl/gnome_3383_screen_glitches_and_freezes_with_black/

- launchpad Bug Report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1923864
- launchpad Question: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/696573

Comment: Please describe your issue and eventually include some screenshots. Not everyone here is prepared to go over for watching video's.

Comment: really i can't take screenshots but i added some additional info....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be this

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1924624

Effected thousands of users, to do with kernal version update, u can temporarily fix this by reverting to an older kernal version, or you can wait till it's fixed